# Code Breaks Out of Iteration - Only Printing First Item

Tags: python

I have folders in a directory named 2001,2002,2003,2004,2005. However when I iterate through them inside the 'for batch in batchno:
print(batch)' It only prints the first one 2001. If I print the parameter "Batchno", it gives me all folders. IS there something breaking out of the loop that I am missing? I read that a return can break out of your loop, not sure if "return filename" is doing that.

```py
def getCOAFilePaths(batchno, pdkey):

    for date in pdkey:
        date = date

    for batch in batchno:
        print(batch)
        filepath = f'\\\test/User/000/000/{date}/IMGCD/{batch}/'
        abspth = os.path.abspath(filepath)
        for row in os.listdir(filepath):
            print(abspth+"\\"+row)
            logging.info(abspth+"\\"+row)

        return filepath

    makePdf(filepath, r'C:\Users\TEST\COA\misc.fof')


def makePdf(filepath, SaveToDir):

    os.chdir(filepath)
    try:
        for j in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
           os.chdir(filepath)
           fname, fext= os.path.splitext(j)
           newfilename = fname + ".pdf"
           im = Image.open(fname + fext)
           os.chdir(SaveToDir)
           im.save(newfilename, "PDF", resolution=100.0)
    except Image.UnidentifiedImageError:
            print(f"{fname+fext} found. Skipping UnidentifiedImageError error because this library cannot open a  .db file "
            f"and convert it to pdf.")


    makePdf(filepath, r'C:\Users\TEST\COA\misc.fof')
    filepath = getCOAFilePaths(x1, x5)
```

output:

```
 2001
```

expected output:

```
2001,2002,2003,2004,2005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a return will end execution of a loop.
Try accumulating your result values and return them together after the `for` has completed.

Example using a list to accumulate the values

```
filepaths = [] # Create an empty list
for batch in batchno:
    print(batch)
    filepath = f'\\\test/User/000/000/{date}/IMGCD/{batch}/'
    abspth = os.path.abspath(filepath)
    for row in os.listdir(filepath):
        print(abspth+"\\"+row)
        logging.info(abspth+"\\"+row)

    filepaths.append(filepath) # Accumulate values here

return filepaths # Return the list once completed the loop
```

Edit:

In case you only need those values to call the `makePdf` function you can also directly call the function inside the loop, without returning anything

```
for batch in batchno:
    print(batch)
    filepath = f'\\\test/User/000/000/{date}/IMGCD/{batch}/'
    abspth = os.path.abspath(filepath)
    for row in os.listdir(filepath):
        print(abspth+"\\"+row)
        logging.info(abspth+"\\"+row)

    makePdf(filepath, r'C:\Users\TEST\COA\misc.fof')
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! It's hitting your **return** at the end of the first iteration of the for loop

If I'm interpreting what you're attempting to do correctly, you can simply remove the **return** and your code should run fine

Comment: Do I have to return it more to the left? I need that filepath variable to use it in another function.

Comment: @Ben21 - no because you're calling your other function from within the function that defines that variable

Answer (score 0):

You have used "return" inside the for-loop so as the first iteration ends it will come out of the function